# Can I simply install a higher amperage breaker on an existing circuit?

Tags: electrical, old-house

I have 6 refrigerators plugged in on 1 breaker.

If I add any more, and I do need to add 4 more, and the breaker keeps tripping can I change it to a higher amp one?

Comment: You aren't likely to run 10 fridges on one breaker. Breakers correspond to the wires that are in use. For example, a 15A breaker needs at least 14AWG wire. You **can't** change the breaker without considering all of the wire that the breaker serves. If you provide more detail in the question, we might be able to help.

Comment: Even running 6 on one regular(right size) breaker that does not trip often is odd.

Comment: **OP, we need to know more about your circuit.  Does your circuit breaker have a TEST button?** Modern refrigerators only take about 100W when running and maybe 1000W for the <1 second when they are starting.  Unless one is acquiring refrigerators off of curbs on junk day, 10 *new* refrigerators on 1 circuit shouldn't be a problem.  (starting them all after an outage would be interesting, since they'll all startup surge at the same time. You'd have to unplug them all and plug them in 1-2 at a time. Once they're working, 2 starting *in the same second* isn't likely.

Comment: Modern ones still suck down ~200W when defrosting, typically. And that's an "actually efficient" modern one - some are considerably less efficient than that particular one, and if you have an icemaker there's another heating element going off.

Answer (score 7):

NO, you **cannot** exchange the breaker for a bigger one.

Instead you should run a new circuit (or a few) from the panel to the fridges.

Or given that you need 10 fridges you can inquire about a commercial cooling solution where the coolant circuit is shared between the fridges. Or where the power consumption is coordinated between the fridges so they don't all turn on at the same time.

Answer (score 7):

Breakers protect the wires they are attached to from overheating and causing your building to burn.

As such, it is very rare for the wire connected between the breaker and your load (fridges) to be large enough to permit "just changing the breaker to a bigger one" without causing the wire to overheat and possibly cause a fire (which will impact the contents of your fridges in a negative way.)

It's also typical (though variable by how each country does things) for too large a circuit feeding a particular type of receptacle to cause unsafe conditions by providing more power to a faulted appliance than it was rated for, possibly resulting in a different cause of fire and shock hazard while not tripping the breaker.

So, the correct approach is to run a **new** circuit on **new** wire with an **additional circuit breaker** feeding it, and only put 5 or 6 fridges on each one, if 6 fridges works fine on the circuit you have now. **In any case, both the new and old circuits should be sized correctly for the load.** That might mean 2 new circuits for a total of 3, for instance, if the current circuit is actually overloaded with 6, but not *so* overloaded it trips, normally.

Answer (score 5):

No, do NOT do this.

If you need more capacity, then run a new circuit or circuits to that area with the appropriate breakers. Perhaps 5 on one and 5 on the other...

If you cannot do this then get an electrician to do so.

The consequences of getting this wrong could be a fire.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 10 refrigerators, you have a bunch of people there. When you have a bunch of people, the electricity needs to be *tip-top*!  Or else [bad things happen](https://www.sfchronicle.com/oakland-fire/) and then you go to prison.

So enlarging the breaker is *out of the question*. Breakers protect wires, and the breaker size is determined by the wire size.  If the wire has to be replaced to enlarge the breaker, well gosh -- the hard part is finding the route for the cable.  Once you have the route, it's just as easy installing 2 cables as 1, and then you have 3 total circuits and can go 2 fridges per circuit.

Comment: This sounds like a commercial installation, who has 6 fridges and needs 4 more?   If so, it's probably not code legal (depending of course where he is) to DIY wiring in a commercial setting.   Even if not commercial...he should think about tripping a breaker, maybe if he's not there for a while and loose 10 fridges worth of food.  2 circuits at least.